# How to run a test multiple times in Cypress.io

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, cypress

I have a test case to fix a bug that appears *1 in X times*.

I'd like to run the same test multiple times but I can't find any documentation that explains how to restart the test automatically and stop when a threshold is hit.

Any insight is appreciated

Comment: What does the test look like? Perhaps wrap it in a command, then call the command in a for loop. Though, the failure will still show up in the results.

Answer (score 27):

Instead of putting the loop inside the test, you could put it in the outer space as following

```
var i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 3 ; i++) {     
  describe('Verify "Login" is visible. Test: '+i, function() {
    it('finds the Login link in the header', function() {

      //Place code inside the loop that you want to repeat

    })
  })
}
```

The Result will be the following:

- Verify "Login" is visible. Test: 0
- finds the Login link in the header
- Verify "Login" is visible. Test: 1
- finds the Login link in the header
- Verify "Login" is visible. Test: 2
- finds the Login link in the header

Comment: Brilliant! Sometimes I have to be reminded it's all just JavaScript, no special language syntax, allowing for use-cases such as this.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. It says "No commands were issued in this test."

Comment: you can encapsulate the it() function itself inside the for loop instead of creating new describe for each test

Answer (score 24):

You can add the testing block inside a loop.

Cypress is [bundled with a few libraries](https://docs.cypress.io/api/utilities/_#Syntax), [lodash](https://lodash.com/) can do this using: [Cypress._.times](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#times) method:

```js
Cypress._.times(10, () => {
  describe('Description', () => {
    it('runs 10 times', () => {
      //...
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I suggest this method as each loop is it's own test, failing and capturing isolated output.

Answer (score 16):

I completely spaced and forgot that these are normal JS files, so I wrapped the test in a for loop. This seems to work as I expected.

```
describe('Verify "Login" is visible', function() {
  it('finds the Login link in the header', function() {
    var i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 5 ; i++) { 
      //Place code inside the loop that you want to repeat
      cy.visit('https://www.example.com/page1')
      cy.get('.navbar').contains('Login').should('be.visible')
      cy.visit('https://www.example.com/page2')
      cy.get('.navbar').contains('Login').should('be.visible')
    }      
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also put the loop outside the it or describe calls. This way the Cypress Test Runner UI will show you a pass or fail for each distinct iteration of the loop. In my experience this is the better way to do it since a failure will continue next iteration.

```
describe('Visit multiple pages', function() {
    //array of values to try
    ['example.com/1','example.com/2','example.com/3']
        // unique test run for each url
        .forEach( (url)=>{
            // can use parameters in test names
            it(`we can visit ${url}`, function() {      
                cy.visit(url)
            })
    })
})
```

Comment: You might want to add a specific code snippet here to show them how to go about doing that, or a screen shot might also help.

Can you elaborate by what you mean in saying "Put a loop above the describe/it pair"?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/test-retries#How-It-Works.

You can configure this in your configuration file (cypress.json by default) by passing the retries option an object with the following options:

runMode allows you to define the number of test retries when running cypress run
openMode allows you to define the number of test retries when running cypress open

```
{
  "retries": {
    // Configure retry attempts for `cypress run`
    // Default is 0
    "runMode": 2,
    // Configure retry attempts for `cypress open`
    // Default is 0
    "openMode": 0
  }
}
```

Comment: This retries failed tests until they succeed. OP wants to repeat a successful test until it fails.